# My boss wants me to use a certain program on my computer

Tags: software-development, conflict-resolution

So my boss wants me to use Outlook as my email client. His main reason is because he wants to standardize, which I can understand. Another reason he pointed out that he wants me to use Outlook is because I didn't receive an email from him. However, I didn't receive the email because our email server was spotty today. It crashed and emails slowly began trickling in after it came back online. That's the real reason I didn't receive it, but due to his hatred of all things non-Microsoft, he blames it on my email client.

I do use Outlook, but only when I'm in a virtual machine (my main OS is Linux). If I were to use Outlook, I would need to keep the virtual machine open 100% of the time so I don't miss emails. On my current system that's not realistic. It doesn't have the RAM or CPU to handle a virtual machine all the time. I usually only open the virtual machine for a couple hours at a time for specific stuff.

Would it be acceptable to tell him I need a new computer to keep my virtual machine open 100% of the time? I'm afraid that he will force me to switch to Windows as my main OS. He dislikes Linux, but a lot of our projects use it in embedded applications. I'm also just much more proficient with it than Windows.

Comment: Is your boss not from technical background? Can you just use a web email client in Linux to confirm you didn't get the email?

Comment: Your question is "is this action acceptable to my boss?"  We don't know. Ask your boss if it is acceptable to them.  This question is not answerable by anyone except that person, so it is not clear why you're asking people on the internet.

Comment: Leaving aside that you've posted a question that no one could possibly know the answer to -- is it your intention to tell your boss "*I will be unproductive in the operating system most commonly used to facilitate business operations?*" Do you think that will reflect well or poorly on you should opportunities for promotion arise?

Comment: @jcmack I checked in Outlook and I didn't receive the email there either. After about 20 minutes the email appeared in both of my email clients.

Comment: @EricLippert I understand where you're coming from, but like I said, I work on Linux because our products are mainly Linux. Would you take away a nail gun from a carpenter in return for a hammer, just because you wanted to standardize tool brand? Then tell the carpenter, "are you telling me you'll be unproductive because you are using one of the most common tools in this business? I may pass you up for a promotion"

Comment: Are you able to access the exchange server through the outlook web page?

Comment: @Snow yes I can use outlook online, but it's not as user friendly and doesn't have the same feature set as Outlook desktop or my current email client.

Comment: I'm not the person you should be making that argument to; your boss is that person. Again, it's not clear to me why you're asking a question that only one person knows the answer to.

Comment: @Joffrey I hate to say this but outlook is a much better MUA. Would not using windows as your primary OS and use X windows or telnet to develop on an actual server or if you must develop locally use hyper V and run a vm on that.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I think that OP is using "miss" in the sense of "not see immediately", here, though I fail to see why that would be a bad thing. Employees can be more productive if they limit their access to emails to a few times per day, so they can work uninterrupted the rest of the day. (Obviously, that only holds if replying to emails is not a big part of their job.)

Comment: Most places with on premises Microsoft Exchange also have Outlook Web Access (OWA) setup so you just need a web browser to access your mail.

Answer (score 4):

I feel with you, I spend two weeks at work trying to make an email client work with what gmail calls IMAP. It didn't work and I had to give up, learning the horrible UI that gmail provides, and to this day I am still occasionally losing emails, because of googles weird tagging semantics. 
Turns out I am still better at replying to emails than most of my colleagues.

But in the end we are a professionals doing a job. Part of our job is to use and learn technology needed for the job, that includes email programs might not be our favorites.
Trying to fight back against a company decision that works for 99% of your colleagues just make you look like someone who cannot adept, this is not label that will get your far in software development.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to add Outlook to your phone.

There are lots of reasons **not** to do this but it may be an acceptable trade off in your specific situation. It isn't a good platform for resolving emails but does tick the boxes for being Outlook and for allowing you to receive emails without needing a virtual machine.

Obviously this comes with some huge potential downsides.